# Firebase Realtime Database permission denied with orderByChild

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a database with a collection of `exchanges` (exchange is just a general word for anything exchanged between people... just think of them in this case only as text messages) for a conversation. The collection contains each conversation, inside which are the exchanges. I am trying to fetch these exchanges sorted by its `date` property (which contains a ServerValue.timestamp). For some reason, with the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
}
```

I am unable to do this without getting a ´permission-denied´.

Here is the code I am using in Flutter:

```
DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = await realtimeDatabase.ref('exchanges/$id').orderByChild('date').get();
```

The data for an exchange looks like this:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code queries a node called `exchanges`, but no such node is present in your security rules (nor in the JSON you showed) which means that noone can read the none.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, yes you are right. I edited the rules to match the collection name. Still gives me a 'permission-denied'. If it's worth mentioning, I also tried the rules with full access (read and write = true) but still denied...

Comment: If you tried it with simpler rules and get the same problem, show us the simpler rules **instead** of the more complex ones. The simpler the [repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the more likely it is that someone can help.

Comment: Hey, Did you find a solution for this?